# Axios catching a Promise Error

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have the following axios call:

```
axios.put({API_IMAGE_URL}}`, imageData, { withCredentials: true, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } })
                .then(response => {
                    axios.get(`${API_URL}/images/${response.data.id}`, { withCredentials: true, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } })
                        .then(response => {
                            var newFormat = response.data;
                            dispatch(updateFormat(newFormat))
                        });
                }).catch((e) => {
                    console.log("Can't update image ", e);
```

Essentially I have an image object that gets passed to a url. From there, I need to retrieve the new Image object with it's new ID to be used for other things.

If my image is too big, I the following errors:

```
413 (Request Entity Too Large)
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
```

My problem lies here. It gives me these errors and DOES NOT go to the catch clause. Is there a way to catch these promise errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return the second axios promise like this

```
    axios.put({API_IMAGE_URL}}`, imageData, { withCredentials: true, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }).then(response => {
        // Return the promise from here like this
        return axios.get(`${API_URL}/images/${response.data.id}`, { withCredentials: true, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }).then(response => {
            var newFormat = response.data;
            dispatch(updateFormat(newFormat))
       });
   }).catch((e) => {
       console.log("Can't update image ", e);
```

Comment: Thanks! Just tried this, I'm still getting the Network errors, instead of catching them

Comment: Oh nvm just was looking at the wrong funciton, it works!